# Is there a method to change the responseType to arraybuffer in XMLHttpRequest when async:false and using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, jsdom

I'm scraping images from a comic site and it uses an encryption algorithm to retrieve the images and parse it to a blob link. I want to stop at the decryption and return the `Uint8Array` and use python code to write it to a file.

```py
import execjs

def rfc(nam):
    with open(nam, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()

def decryptedData(lnk):
    js = execjs.compile(rfc('getAndDecrypt.js'))
    resp = js.call('i', lnk)
    return bytes(list(resp.values()))

res = decryptedData('https://img.mwimser2.cc/static/upload/book/id/18928/547567/4c8ca89af48c44d45893f959b16447b2.webp?v=20220724')
with open('a.webp', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res)
```

```js
// getAndDecrypt.js: get and decrypt image
let CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")
let jsdom = require("jsdom")
let { JSDOM } = jsdom
let dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body></body></html>`)
window = dom.window
document = window.document
XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest

var r = "my2ecret782ecret"

function i(e) {
    let a = new XMLHttpRequest;
    a.open("GET", e, false)
    a.responseType = "arraybuffer" //this line gets changed
    a.send()
    return d(s2b(a.response), r)
}

function o(e) {
    let t = e.sigBytes,
        r = e.words,
        a = new Uint8Array(t);
    for (var n = 0, s = 0; n != t;) {
        var i = r[s++];
        if (a[n++] = (4278190080 & i) >>> 24, n == t) break;
        if (a[n++] = (16711680 & i) >>> 16, n == t) break;
        if (a[n++] = (65280 & i) >>> 8, n == t) break;
        a[n++] = 255 & i
    }
    return a
}
function d(r, a) {
    let s = r,
        i = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(a),
        l = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(s),
        f = o(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
            ciphertext: l
        }, i, {
            iv: i,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }));
        return f;
}
```

The link is [here](https://manwa.life/chapter/547567) if you want to further investigate it.

```js
$(function () {
    webpMachine.webpSupport.then(e => {
        var t = !1,
            r = "my";
        let a, n, s = "ret";
        async function i(e, t) {
            let a = new XMLHttpRequest;
            a.open("GET", e, !0), a.responseType = "arraybuffer", a.onload = async function () {
                4 == a.readyState && (200 == a.status ? t.src = await d(a.response, r, t) : (console.log(key, e), f(e, key)))
            }, a.send()
        }

        function o(e) {
            const t = e.sigBytes,
                r = e.words,
                a = new Uint8Array(t);
            for (var n = 0, s = 0; n != t;) {
                var i = r[s++];
                if (a[n++] = (4278190080 & i) >>> 24, n == t) break;
                if (a[n++] = (16711680 & i) >>> 16, n == t) break;
                if (a[n++] = (65280 & i) >>> 8, n == t) break;
                a[n++] = 255 & i
            }
            return a
        }
        r += "2ecret", r += "782ec", r += "ret", $("img.lazy_img").each(function (e) {
            $(this).attr("data-original", "/static/images/imagecover.png"), $(this).on("load", function () {
                ($(this).attr("src").indexOf("blob:") > -1 || $(this).attr("src").indexOf("base64") > -1) && ($(this).css("width", "auto").css("display", "flex").css("min-height", "0px"), window.URL.revokeObjectURL($(this).attr("src")))
            })
        }), $("img.lazy_img").lazyload({
            threshold: 1500,
            effect: "fadeIn",
            load: function (e) {
                let t = $(this)[0],
                    r = t.getAttribute("src");
                r.indexOf("blob:") < 0 && r.indexOf("base64") && i(t.getAttribute("data-r-src"), t)
            }
        });
        const c = e => new Promise(t => setTimeout(t, e)),
            l = e => {
                let t = new FileReader;
                return t.readAsDataURL(e), new Promise(e => {
                    t.onloadend = (() => {
                        e(t.result)
                    })
                })
            };
        async function d(r, a, n) {
            let s = r,
                i = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(a),
                l = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(s),
                d, f = o(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
                    ciphertext: l
                }, i, {
                    iv: i,
                    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
                })),
                p = "";
            if (e) {
                let e = new Blob([f]);
                p = URL.createObjectURL(e)
            } else {
                let e = 0;
                for (;
                    "" === p && e < 100;) {
                    if (e++, !t) {
                        let e;
                        t = !0, p = await webpMachine.decode(f), t = !1
                    }
                    "" === p && await c(300)
                }
                "" == p && console.log($(n).attr("data-sort"), "fail!!")
            }
            return p
        }

        function f(e, t) {
            let a = new XMLHttpRequest;
            a.open("GET", e, !0), a.responseType = "arraybuffer", a.onload = function () {
                200 == a.status && (t.src = d(a.response, r))
            }, a.send()
        }
    })
});
```

This is the original code. Take a look at the XHR requests for the `webp` files.

nodejs version: `v18.3.0`

Comment: Hey guys. I fixed this problem by putting the code for the request in python with `res = list(requests.get(lnk, timeout = 1).content)` and beaming it over to the js file in a `list` from a `bytes` object. I parse it to an `ArrayBuffer` using `new Uint8Array(e).buffer` But if I'm writing pure js code, this won't work, so the question's still open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to use `XMLHttpRequest` has to be under an html page to set `responseType` with synchronous programming. Thus, the best way is to put code inside python and pass it in as a parameter. If you are using this inside a js app, I recommend finding another way to use it or just go ahead with javascript promises.